# Custom vertical lines with pgfgantt (pgf multiplier issues)

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfgantt

I'm having some issues drawing vertical lines in a ganttchart (using the `pgfgantt` package). The approach is to define the bars in the chart using a `dd-mm-yyyy` format but only showing the months.

To keep things clear, it would be useful to have vertical (dashed) lines separating the months. I haven't found a way to do this automatically (vgrid draws a line for every single day), so I ended up skipping `(month length - 1)` lines for every month. The main question would be, is there a better way to get the correct vertical lines?

---

Second, the MWE below works in a `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` setting but results in an error when used in a `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}` setting:

`! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/*{30}{draw=none}' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

I'm using pgfgantt version `2013/06/01 v4.0`. Do I need to include additional packages, what's going on?

**[Edit]** This turns out to be a conflict with the `amsmath` package, see comments below. This is now fixed.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=7mm,title height=1,y unit chart=10mm,bar top shift=.2,bar height=.6,bar/.append style={fill=black!10},bar label node/.append style={align=right},progress label text=,hgrid={*1{black!10, dashed}},vgrid={*{29}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}, dashed, *{27}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}, dashed, *{29}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}},x unit=.4mm,time slot format=little-endian]{01-11-2014}{31-05-2015}
\gantttitlecalendar{month=shortname} \\
\ganttbar{Topic I}{16-11-2014}{22-12-2014} 
\ganttbar{}{05-01-2015}{00-02-2015} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Topic II}{16-01-2015}{16-05-2015}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me with `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}`

Comment: @HarishKumar Strange, when I remove all other packages (I only checked it with my LaTeX template using a couple of default packges) it works just fine in that setting. It turns out adding the `amsmath` package results in the error, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that there is an error with `amsmath`. I have to go now so I leave it to others, :)

Comment: The error with `amsmath` can be prevented suppressing blank spaces in the `vgrid` specification. Specifically, suppressing the blank spaces just before the `*` characters, as in  `vgrid={*{29}{draw=none}, dashed,*{30}{draw=none}, dashed,*{30}{draw=none}, dashed,*{27}{draw=none}, dashed,*{30}{draw=none}, dashed,*{29}{draw=none}, dashed,*{30}{draw=none}}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that `amsmath` changes the definition of the macro `\@ifstar` that `pgfgantt` uses to read off the style definitions. You can temporarily restore back the original definition of this macro though I haven't tested whether this breaks down anything in anywhere else. Seems working though. Also you might need to do the same to `hgrid`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\makeatletter
\let\origifstar=\@ifstar
\ganttset{
  vgrid/.code={%
    \begingroup
    \let\@ifstar=\origifstar
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \def\@tempb{false}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
      \gtt@vgridfalse%
    \else%
      \gtt@vgridtrue%
      \def\@tempb{true}%
      \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
        \def\gtt@vgridstyle{dotted}%
      \else%
        \def\gtt@vgridstyle{#1}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \endgroup
  },%
  vgrid/.default=dotted
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}%<---- Delay the amsmath loading

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  y unit title=7mm,
  title height=1,
  y unit chart=10mm,
  bar top shift=.2,
  bar height=.6,
  bar/.append style={fill=black!10},
  bar label node/.append style={align=right},
  progress label text=,hgrid={*1{black!10, dashed}},
  vgrid={ *{29}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}, dashed, *{27}{draw=none}, dashed, *{30}{draw=none}, dashed,*{29}{draw=none},dashed, *{30}{draw=none}},
  x unit=.4mm,time slot format=little-endian]{01-11-2014}{31-05-2015}
\gantttitlecalendar{month=shortname} \\
\ganttbar{Topic I}{16-11-2014}{22-12-2014} 
\ganttbar{}{05-01-2015}{00-02-2015} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Topic II}{16-01-2015}{16-05-2015}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea! Could this calculation work out for this question as well? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509832