# pgfgantt: How to create vgrid in monthly interval?

Tags: rules, pgfgantt, grids

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[%
        time slot format    = isodate,
        vgrid               = { *6{dotted}, *1{dashed} },
        ]%
        {2019-01-01}{2019-02-15}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**The question:**

How can one add additional `vgrid`-lines for each month (like shown in the next screenshot)? Due to irregularities of month durations (some have 28 days while others have 31 days) it is not possible to just add lines for each 31th day. :-)

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

Furthermore, the monthly `vgrid` should be added additionally while the weekly `vgrid` remains preserved.

Comment: I am not sure, but doubt that this is doable without major surgery. That is, one may have to basically add some new command.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: But I think including monthly lines should be a standard feature absolutely, no?

Comment: If “should” means “it would be desirable “, then I agree, but I do not know if it is easy in the sense that one only needs to tweak an existing key.

Comment: Does this show you how to mark the months: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256188

Comment: @Ross: Thanks for the idea! I am not 100 % sure - it seems that the monthly grid in your example is only valid for the `\ganttitlecalendar`, but not for the chart itself, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vgrid` is made using a *style list*. A *style list* is just a sequence of instructions corresponding to the specifications of each line that needs to be drawn. A week begins on a Monday. January 1, 2019 is a Tuesday. Days are separated by dotted gray lines, weeks by dashed black lines and the month end by a red line with a width of 3pt.

So the sequence is 5 dotted lines followed by one dashed line to end the first week: `*5{dotted},*1{dashed}`. This is followed by three full weeks so we repeat `*6{dotted},*1{dashed}`, three times. The end of the month falls in the next week, so we write: `*3{dotted},{red,line width=3pt},*2{dotted},*1{dashed}` to complete week 5 in the chart. Then we add 2 more weeks of the dotted-dashed format to round out the chart.

For clarity, I added the weekday names and week numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\def\pgfcalendarweekdayletter#1{%
\ifcase#1M\or T\or W\or T\or F\or S\or S\fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[%
        time slot format = isodate,
        vgrid = { *5{dotted}, *1{dashed}, % week 1
                  *6{dotted}, *1{dashed}, % week 2
                  *6{dotted}, *1{dashed}, % week 3
                  *6{dotted}, *1{dashed}, % week 4
                  *3{dotted},{red,line width=3pt},*2{dotted}, *1{dashed}, % week 5
                  *6{dotted}, *1{dashed}, % week 6
                  *4{dotted}}]            % week 7
        {2019-01-01}{2019-02-15}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname,week,day,weekday=letter}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The dotted lines are black, not grey as written in text. (Found this post by searching "pgfgantt dotted lines in grey")

Comment: It is absurd we need to do this manually!